# Podman OCI permission to folder issue

Tags: ubuntu, containers, podman

I am attempting to setup a Jellyfin instance using podman on Ubuntu 22.04 and keep getting an OCI permission denied error on my media folders.

```
Error: error stat'ing file `/media/livingroom/Media Disk/Videos`: Permission denied: OCI permission denied
```

There is only one user on the machine and it is the owner of the media folder. There is no OCI user or group on the machine.
[image]

This is the podman run command I am using.  If I understand this correctly it should be passing in my user ID and group ID, which is the owner of the folder. This command works if I run as sudo but would like to run without root.  I just can't figure out what permission I am missing on this folder.

```
  podman run \
 --detach \
 --label "io.containers.autoupdate=registry" \
 --name myjellyfin \
 --publish 8096:8096/tcp \
 --rm \
 --user $(id -u):$(id -g) \
 --userns keep-id \
 --volume jellyfin-cache:/cache:z \
 --volume jellyfin-config:/config:z \
 --mount type=bind,source="/media/livingroom/Media Disk/Videos",destination=/media2,ro=true \
 docker.io/jellyfin/jellyfin:latest
```

Answer (score 1):

I needed to add the allow_other flag to the disk mount options.  Added that, rebooted and got it working.

Comment: Hey, thanks for posting an answer when you found it, but could you elaborate a little bit? Like where you added the option (/etc/fstab I assume?). I have a similar error and don't know, whether I'm not following your solution correctly, or whether there's another underlying problem